# Latency and bandwidth limitation(WAN Emulation)

Tags: proxy, latency, wide-area-network, emulation

I have a requirement to emulate the impact of a new application on the WAN. The WAN bottleneck is a 65MB dedicated pipe between Australia and the UK. I have a setup to generate the traffic, but to monitor the impact on user experience i need a way to emulate bandwidth limiting and packet latency in my development environment.

The correct answer will have the following characteristics:

1. The WAN emulation software must be installable on Linux under a virtual environment
2. The WAN emulation software should allow a packet to be held for a time period to simulate latency
3. The WAN emulation software should enforce a bandwidth limitation which is configurable

Any assistance you could provide would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Will try this out tonight, but based on what i see this is the correct answer. The fact that it is inbuilt in Ubuntu is a big bonus